# select case when spring data jpa 2.4.5

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
I am trying the below query in spring boot jpa : version=2.4.5
```

when I see the show SQL for this query, it is doing select p.name instead of case selection

```
select CASE WHEN (p.name is null) THEN pi.name ELSE p.name END from Product p left join ProductInfo pi ON p.productInfoId=pi.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your select query is hard to read. So use coalesce instead of case when keyword.

Like:

```
select coalesce(p.name, pi.name) as productName from Product p left join ProductInfo pi ON p.productInfoId=pi.id
```

Comment: I also wanted to check empty. found result

Answer (score 0):

fixed by below jpa query

```
select (CASE WHEN (p.name is null OR p.name IS EMPTY) THEN pi.name ELSE p.name END) as name from Product p left join ProductInfo pi ON p.productInfoId=pi.id
```